# Can a Dashboard Designed by DevExpress Winforms Designer be opened by DevExpress web Dashboard viewer?

Tags: web, model-view-controller, devexpress, dashboard

I'm developing some web apps using ASP.NET MVC and the reporting is done using External plugin "DevExpress".  I have completed some of the reports. but Dashboard is required so when I start using the DevExpress web Dashboard Designer, It's not that much flexible as of the Desktop or standalone Dashboard Designer. 
My question is, can I use the Dashboard that I created using the Standalone designer on Web Dashboard Viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the dashboard layout formats are compatible between the web and desktop versions.

Source: [Is web dashboard designer compatible with desktop dashboard designer?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T619932/is-web-dashboard-designer-compatible-with-desktop-dashboard-designer)

Additionally:

> With v15.2.9, we have introduced the Community Technology Preview
>   version of the new ASP.NET Dashboard Designer control that combines
>   both Viewer and Editor functionality, with the capability to switch
>   between the two modes on the client side. **The new End-User Editor for
>   the Web is fully compatible with XML dashboard definitions created in
>   the WinForms** or Visual Studio designers.

Source: [Introduce a dashboard designer for Web applications](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T145915/introduce-a-dashboard-designer-for-web-applications)